# CustomUI XML for a Ribbon in Excel

Tags: excel, xml, ribbon

I'm a newbe inXML

I wrote XML for Excel-Ribbon Tab and I want to add  my custom Tab to the ribbon for a single Excel workbook I have to share with collegues.
Thanks to online docs I've find and followed the procedure described in Microsoft docs:

- Created the customization file in text editor and saved the name **customUI.xml** in a folder named **customUI**

The XML is

```
 <customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
   <ribbon>
     <tabs>
       <tab id="TabEasyQuery" label="Easy Query" insertAfterMso="TabHome">
         <group id="eQgenerale" label="Generale" autoScale="false">
   ... my commands ...
         </group>
       </tab>
     </tabs>
   </ribbon>
 </customui>
```

- Add a **.zip** extension to the Workbook file name and opened the file, extract the **_rels** folder and edited the **.rel** file using text editor adding the relationship:

> ```
> <Relationship Id="frapozzeID" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI.xml" />
> ```

- replace the _rels folder in the .zip pack *(the workbook)*
- copy the customUi folder in the .zip pack
- remove the .zip extension

Everything works fine for a basic-Tab with single Groups and Buttons, but doesn't work if I try to add a **splitButton** and/or **menu**

I have tried to change both the relationship in **.rel** file as follows:

> ```
> <Relationship Id="frapozzeID" Type="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2007/relationships/ui/extensibility" Target="customUI/customUI14.xml" />
> ```

also renaming the file in *customUI*  folder:  *customUI14.xml* and changing the reference in

```
 <customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
   <ribbon>
     <tabs>
       <tab id="TabEasyQuery" label="Easy Query" insertAfterMso="TabHome">
         <group id="eQgenerale" label="Generale" autoScale="false">
   ... my commands ...
         </group>
       </tab>
     </tabs>
   </ribbon>
 </customui>
```

but with no effect.

Comment: SOLVED. it was just to fix the XML code (check it enabling the "show add-in user interface errors") so I can confirm the a/m procedure to add Custom Tab works

Answer (score 0):

It was just to fix the XML code (check it enabling the "show add-in user interface errors") so I can confirm the a/m procedure to add Custom Tab works.